# Migrating data from Teradata to BigQuery through dedicated interconnect

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As the title mentioned, there is a server in my company

- it can not connect to public internet, except using a http proxy
- there is a dedicated interconnect between my company and GCP, and someone shared a VPC (subnet) to me, but I'm not able to modify the details of this VPC
- I need to transfer data from this server to GCP through the shared VPC, (not allowed to use http proxy)

I referred the doc https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/teradata,
but stopped at the step [Initialize the migration agent](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/teradata#initialize_the_migration_agent), because of timeout.

I also checked this doc https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid.
But it's mainly about the configuration on GCP page, I'm even unable to connect to GCP on my server.

(Actually, I've transferred data successfully with http proxy, but now I'm not allowed to use it)

What should I do, could anyone help me step by step ?

Comment: Hi @F.M, So you managed to overcome the issue by changing the DNS configuration?

Comment: correct, by this way, I can connect to *.googleapis.com without any http(s) proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional thing is to change the unbound DNS configuration

```
vi /etc/unbound/conf.d/googleapis.com.conf
```

paste the following text into it

```
server:
    local-zone: "googleapis.com." redirect
    local-data: "googleapis.com. IN CNAME restricted.googleapis.com."
    local-zone: "restricted.googleapis.com." static
    local-data: "restricted.googleapis.com. IN A 199.36.153.4"
    local-data: "restricted.googleapis.com. IN A 199.36.153.5"
    local-data: "restricted.googleapis.com. IN A 199.36.153.6"
    local-data: "restricted.googleapis.com. IN A 199.36.153.7"
```

then restart the unbound service

```
service unbound restart
```